# Surface of revolution has area $2 \pi \bar{h} L$, $L$ the profile curve length, $\bar{h}$ average distance to axis of revolution Raw

Tags: differential-geometry

We were working on an interesting problem as the following:

Let $M$ be a surface of revolution whose profile curve has length $L$. Find a formula for the area of $M$ and interpret it as Area(M) $=2 \pi \bar{h} L,$ where $\bar{h}$ is the average distance from $M$ to the axis of revolution.

My progress:
WLOG the curve parameterized as $(\phi, \psi)$ has the following surface of revolution:

\begin{align*}
x(u, v)&=\phi(v) \cos u\\
y(u, v)&=\phi(v) \sin u\\
z(u, v)&=\psi(v)
\end{align*}

The area is then

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{a}^b \sqrt{EG - F^2} dv\,du
$$

As per http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html, I have:

\begin{array}{l}{E=\phi^{2}} \\ {F=0} \\ {G=\phi^{\prime 2}+\psi^{\prime 2}}\end{array}

Then the above integral is equal to:

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{a}^b \phi \sqrt{\phi'^2 + \psi'^2} dv\,du = 2 \pi \int_{a}^b \phi \sqrt{\phi'^2 + \psi'^2} dv
$$

But the integral part is still not in the form $\bar{h} L$. I do know that $\int_{a}^b \sqrt{\phi'^2 + \psi'^2} dv$ is the length $L$, and if I squint hard enough that $\phi$ part is the distance, but am I done? Can I expand this further?

Comment: Review the definition of average value.

Comment: It might help a little bit, if you're stuck, to assume $G=1$ (by parametrizing the profile curve by arclength ... which you can always do).